# How to set Formik custom component value to Formik value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik, google-places-autocomplete

I'm using Formik for my form with google place auto-complete, I want to render places auto-complete as a custom component in the Formik field.

form.js

```
<Formik initialValues={location:""}>
 <Field name="location" component={PlacesAutoComplete} placeholder="enter your location"/>
{...rest of form}
</Formik>
```

auto-complete component

```
  import PlacesAutocomplete , {
  geocodeByAddress,
  geocodeByPlaceId
} from "react-google-places-autocomplete";

export const PlacesAutoComplete = ({
  field: { name, ...field }, // { name, value, onChange, onBlur }
  form: { touched, errors }, // also values, setXXXX, handleXXXX, dirty, isValid, status, etc.
  classes,
  label,
  ...props
}: any) => {
  const [fieldName, setFildName] = React.useState(field.name);
  const [address, setAddress] = React.useState(props.value || "");

  const error = errors[name];
  // const touch = touched[name];

  const handleSelect = () => {
    // set this value to formik value
  };

  const handleChange = () => {
    // set this value to formik value
  };
  const handleError = () => {
    props.form.setFieldError(fieldName, error);
  };


  return (
    <PlacesAutocomplete
      value={address}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onSelect={handleSelect}
      onError={handleError}
      name={name}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      id={name}
      {...props}
      apiKey="Api key here"
    >
      {({
        getInputProps,
        suggestions,
        getSuggestionItemProps,
        loading
      }: any) => (
        <div>
          <input
            {...getInputProps({
              placeholder: "Search Places ...",
              className: "location-search-input form-control"
            })}
          />
          <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container">
            {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
            {suggestions.map((suggestion: any) => {
              const className = suggestion.active
                ? "suggestion-item--active"
                : "suggestion-item";
              // inline style for demonstration purpose
              const style = suggestion.active
                ? { backgroundColor: "#fafafa", cursor: "pointer" }
                : { backgroundColor: "#ffffff", cursor: "pointer" };
              return (
                <div
                  {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                    className,
                    style
                  })}
                >
                  <span>{suggestion.description}</span>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </PlacesAutocomplete>
  );
};
```

How I set places auto-complete value to formik value, I'm pretty new to react and confused in handle change and on change functions. also, I found a solution in react class component [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/73vvjzm56?file=/src/FormikPlacesAutocomplete.jsx:759-775), But when converting those codes into functional components I'm stuck in Onchange and onSlecet functions

Answer (score 0):

Better not write functional components as you'll get stuck with the test cases if you are writing.

OnChange is even you type anything, the value gets stored in onChange.
Abe onSelect is when you select anything

Comment: yes I know it, problem is set places component value to Formik

Answer (score 0):

Basically on change you need to call formik's field onChange function. So in case you get an event on handleChange, just do this

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    // set this value to formik value
    field.onChange(event.target.value)
  };
```

or in case you get value in handleChange then do this

```
const handleChange = (value) => {
    // set this value to formik value
    field.onChange(value)
  };
```

This will sync your formik state with autocomplete state.

Now comes the part for select. In this case also you can take the same route

```
 const handleSelect = (value) => {
    // set this value to formik value
    field.onChange(value)
  };
```

or you can use the setField function of form to update the value

```
 const handleSelect = (value) => {
    // set this value to formik value
    form.setField('location',value)
  };
```